# How to convert char to system.drawing.image(picture box)

Tags: c#, image-processing

I need to get the output to a picture box and text file. but i get an error as Cannot implicitly convert type 'char' to system.drawing.image.

```
                    var color = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
                    var brightness = Brightness(color);
                    var idx = brightness / 255 * (pixels.Length - 1);
                    var pxl = pixels[pixels.Length - (int)Math.Round(idx) - 1];

                    pictureBox2.Image = pxl;  //error
```

Comment: You can only assign an `Image` object to the `Image` property of a `PictureBox`. The error message indicates that `pixels` is an `IList<char>` of some sort. Why do you think that you should be able to get an item from that list and display it in a `PictureBox`? Try providing a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem, like what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Look like you habe a mysterious array or list or pixels you don't tell us anything about and want to bring one of them back to the picturebox's image? Try: `((Bitmap)pictureBox2.Image).SetPixel(x, y, pxl)`

Comment: You need to actually paint that character onto a `Bitmap` before you can use it in a picture box. Which requires all kinds of extra stuff, like an image to paint on, a font, and a font size...